# update-php class causing 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, nginx

update  -now apache is not giving any error. i have seen this earlier also. 99% times it will throw error 500 .see this screenshot. it shows no error at all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxQmk.jpg

i dont know how to solve this problem. it will again start showing after sometimes

i have created one page which seems to be normal page when we open but in chrome and mozilla it gives error.

```
      Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/behNc.jpg
page is http://xxxxxx.com/mobile-under-10000

and i have found that  if i change the name of link to http://xxxxxxx.com/mobile and add class it gives no error.i  cant add php class in mobile-under-10000 as class will not allow - but i really need that name as its seo friendly. 
  if i create pages like this it works but i have to choose only one word in classname. i have thousands of links which is working fine but giving 500 error.

```
<?php
class samplelink {
    function index() {
echo 'write something';
    }
}
?>
```

any idea to resolve will be great. i have one option to force apache to stop throwing 500 error.but it is advisable ? i am using nginx with apache.

please advise

my .htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${LeechProtect:/home/xxxxxx/public_html:%{REMOTE_USER}:%{REMOTE_ADDR}:10} leech
RewriteRule .* http://xxxxxx.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_/\-]+)/$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_/\-]+)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>


RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xxxxx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://xxxxxx.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Read. Error. Logs.

Comment: @u_mulder sorry i did not mentioned error log in question. i checked error log of  apache and nginx . nothing was there

Comment: Show us your website tree. Do you have a folder named `mobile-under-10000` in which you have an `index.php` containing this class ?

Comment: @Zeratops no i dont have.these are modules. see other modules like http://way2enjoy.com/helicopter which does not give any error because i have declared class name as helicopter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Apache, *and* PHP / MySQL error logs are empty then there's a very strong likelyhood the issue is caused by `.htaccess` / `httpd.conf` so check these files for inconsistencies.

> and i have found that if i change the name of link to http://way2enjoy.com/mobile and add class it gives no error

This strongly indicates that you have not properly escaped characters in your `.htaccess`.

**EDIT**

These lines:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_/\-]+)/$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA]
> RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_/\-]+)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA]
> ```

Can be rewritten and fully escaped as :

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_\/\-]+)/?$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA]
```

There are some curious behaviours that are in your `htaccess` but nothing jumps out at me as potential fatal issues.

Some points:

- You state `reWriteEngine On` three times in your htaccess, this may cause an error and so you can remove two times.

I have re-organise your code so :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z_\/\-]+)/?$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA]

 RewriteCond ${LeechProtect:/home/xxxxxx/public_html:%{REMOTE_USER}:%{REMOTE_ADDR}:10} leech
 RewriteRule .* http://xxxxxx.com

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xxxxx\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ http://xxxxxx.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>

 RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

The final line returns a Forbidden header result (403) if it is ever reached, which seems to be quite heavy handed and possibly unnessecary response.

I also question the `leechProtect` statement but don't know enough about it to advise further. But use the code above and then check your site commenting out (`#comment`) each line and then clearing your browser cache (each time, as browsers cache htaccess rules) and see if commenting out some of these requests causes the site not to return `500` errors.

Good luck.

Comment: poop. Ok, So even if you delete (or better save and rename) the `.htaccess` file (and remember to clear your browser history cache for the site too) you still get the error 500s?